# How do I write this foreach loop as any other kind of loop?

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach ($a as $b)
{
do function
}
```

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i <= count($a); $i++) 
 { $b = $a[$i]; }

Comment: Count assumes the availability of a count method.  foreach uses the iterator interface which doesn't guarantee a count method.

Comment: If $a is an array, you can do $keys = array_keys($a) and then loop over $keys with the normal $i < count($a) loop. But a bit more context would be helpful to provide the answer you need, we're just guessing now...

Comment: @jmucchiello — The "any other kind" bit makes me suspect this is homework.

Answer (score 4):

```
while ($b.MoveNext())
{
    $a = $b.Current;
}
```

Comment: you mean `->` instead `.` right? given that was tagged as *php*

Answer (score 4):

```
reset($a);
while (list($key, $value) = each($a)) { 
  //...
}

$keys = array_keys($a);
while (($key = array_shift($keys)) !== NULL))
{
  $b = $a[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($a))
{
  $b = $a[$i];

  //do function

  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Good, but the count might not be available for all enumerations.

Comment: also, this assumes that keys are integers from 0 to the count - 1, which is not necessarily the case

Comment: It would also be more efficient to place the count() outside of the loop to prevent recounting the array every single time.

Comment: The count() is only executed once, that's how the while loop works.

Comment: @luvieere: a while loop executes its test at the beginning of each iteration through the loop.  In your example, `count($a)` will be executed multiple times.  If you want to test this, try `function mycount($a) { echo 'test'; return count($a); }` and then `while ($i < mycount($a))`